# Intersection of a plane with 3D graphics box not entirely shown

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions

I'm getting something a bit deceiving with this very simple code :

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, u/2 + v},
    {u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 2},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}},
    Mesh -> None,
    PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.1]},
    BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray],
    Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: plot]

It draws a simple tilted plane inside the 3D boxed frame, with borders shown around the plane.  However, a border is missing on the top side of the frame.  I understand that it's actually outside, since the border is defined on the **{u, v}** domain.

So how can I show a complete border all around the plane, *inside* the frame box ?

Comment: What if you dilate your `PlotRange` slightly (i.e. add/subtract a tiny extra to those numbers)?

Comment: Dilating the PlotRange will not do it.  The missing border is well outside the box, because it's defined on the **{u, v}** domain.

Comment: @J.M. There isn't a boundary at the top. The parallelogram is being clipped. Cham, try adding `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z < 2]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, your suggestion works.  I'll try it in my full code.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: To amplify upon comment by @MichaelE2, to display the full plane segment defined by the parameters, use `PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}}` and then the upper boundary will be shown.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need use `RegionPlot3D` to confine the plot to a region. You can give the region to `ParametricPlot3D`. You get a bonus: you no longer need `PlotRange`.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, u/2 + v}, 
  {u, v} ∈ ImplicitRegion[u/2 + v <= 2, {{u, 0, 2}, {v, 0, 2}}],
  Mesh -> None,
  PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.1]},
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black],
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use also use [`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html)

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= u <= 2 && 0 <= v <= 2 && z == u/2 + v,
   {u, v, z}];
```

Since a plane has no thickness, you would need to use [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html) ("In particular, [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html) will attempt to discretize lower-dimensional parts of reg.").

To display the boundary more clearly I changed it to `Thick`

```
RegionPlot3D[
 DiscretizeRegion@reg,
 PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.1]},
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Gray]]
```

[image]

Comment: If memory serves, the OP is using a version that does not yet have `DiscretizeRegion[]` as a built-in. Alternatively, for those with newer versions, using `InfinitePlane[]` might be a cheaper route.